# Unable to render correct page in Flask Web App

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

Hi please help me out with this - When I try to run http://127.0.0.1:5000/ which basically renders the home.html or FRONT PAGE of my website, I want it to render the correct template like If the user is admin (I determine that by a 6 digit admcode defined in models.py) It should render admhome.html otherwise it should render just home.html which is for normal user but in my views.py the views.route ='/' can render one template at a time, I tried to overcome that by putting an IF statement that used something like this -

```
if current_user.admcode == "":
    
    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user, movies=user_searched_movies)
else:
    
    return render_template("admhome.html", user=current_user, movies=user_searched_movies)
```

I was expecting it to get the correct home page as per the type of user but it is not happening

Can you guys let me know If I can do anything that would help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using the wrong approach to check your conditions.The is no middle-ground between a digit and a string, yet you are checking base on string. Consider this one: if the `admcode` is not defined any other integer(digit) would still pass the condition to be admin because no integer is an empty string `""`.

What I would suggest is to use a boolean instead, with a `current_user.is_admin` set to `True` when the user is admin and `False` otherwise. That would change you code to the following:

```
if not current_user.is_admin:

    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user, movies=user_searched_movies)
else:

    return render_template("admhome.html", user=current_user, movies=user_searched_movies)
```

The other alternative would be to make sure your `current_user.admcode` is either a digit everywhere or a string everywhere. That way, if it is a string and admin would have a tring with some content(any number of digits) and the non-admin and empty string. If the `current_user.admcode` happens to be a digit everywhere, then you give the non-admin user `0` as the value and you check for `if current_user.admcode == 0` istead of `if current_user.admcode == ""`. Still I genuinely recommend the boolean approach with `current_user.is_admin`